# same height 3 columns menu with HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with a fixed menu for my web app. I wanted to have a fixed menu in the top of my page with a title in the middle and two buttons at every side: back and next.

[image]

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-back-button">Ac1</div>
    <div id="header-title">
        <h1>This is my so so so long title</h1></div>
    <div id="header-next-button">Ac2</div>
</div>

#header{
    display: inline;
}
#header-back-button{
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    background: orange; 
}
#header-title {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 40px;
    background: yellow;
}
#header-next-button {
    float: right;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    background: orange;
}
```

The problem is I really need my site to be responsive, so when I resize the windows it has to rezise the dom elements. When I have a long title, the div becames with two lines, and the space covered is the double. There are no problem with such thing, except for the other divs are not being resized. SO, how can I resize such divs?

Thanks a lot!

http://jsfiddle.net/x7dsLkoe/7/

Comment: dont you want to use bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very easy. Change your CSS like this:

```
#header {
    display: table;
    width:100%
}
#header-back-button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    background: orange;
}
#header-title {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 40px;
    background: yellow;
}
#header-next-button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    background: orange;
}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dw2mrzhx/)

Answer (score 1):

Just for a few other options, you could:

- Display the header as a table. http://jsfiddle.net/5bavL6s4/
- Using flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/ezj55frk/
- Set the height of your back/next buttons with javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/zsLm1yvb/

  `$('#header-back-button, #header-next-button').height($('#header-title').height());`
- Force a one row title with 'white-space:no-wrap;' and 'text-overflow:elipsis;' on your H1.
- Change your design. :P

Personally, I would opt for altering the design to be able to fit two lines by default. By setting the height of title and buttons explicitly.

Displaying as a table is easy, but you would be going against the ["don't use tables as layout"-sentiment](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html#tablescanbegood).

Flexbox is cool but browser support is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `display: table-cell;`. [Here's a jsfiddle variation](http://jsfiddle.net/qgmec1so/Fixed).

Comment: I think you post my JSFiddle instead of yours.

Comment: So sorry about that. Fixed in the response now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to `#header` class and add this to each column's class:

```
margin-bottom: -99999px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
```

Also i think you need to remove `display: inline;` from `#header` class.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7dsLkoe/10/)**